# On-screen keyboard does not appear on screen upon focus of input in browser

Tags: fedora, keyboard, gnome3, accessibility

I am using Fedora 21. I have activated the on-screen keyboard using the universal access. I cannot get the on-screen keyboard to appear when working in a browser, LibreOffice Calc or directory. The only time it pops up is when I am using the terminal. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I see the same behaviour on Fedora 23. It might be bug.

Comment: Which keyboard? Is it on-board?